# Reference method with array constructor

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

I tried to use reference method with expression `ArrayType[]::new` in the following example:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        test1(3,A[]::new);
        test2(x -> new A[] { new A(), new A(), new A() });

        test3(A::new);
    }

    static void test1(int size, IntFunction<A[]> s)
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.apply(size)));
    }

    static void test2(IntFunction<A[]> s)
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.apply(3)));
    }

    static void test3(Supplier<A> s)
    {
        System.out.println(s.get());
    }
}

class A
{
    static int count = 0;
    int value = 0;

    A()
    {
        value = count++;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return Integer.toString(value);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[null, null, null]
[0, 1, 2]
3
```

But what i get in method `test1` is only an array with null elements, shouldn't the expression `ArrayType[]::new` create an array with the specified size and call the construction of class `A` for each element like what happen when using expression `Type::new` in method `test3`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ArrayType[]::new` is a method reference to an array constructor. When you create an instance of an array, the elements are initialized to the default value for the array's type, and the default value for reference types is null.

Just as `new ArrayType[3]` produces an array of 3 `null` references, so does calling `s.apply(3)` when `s` is a method reference to an array constructor (i.e. `ArrayType[]::new`) would produce an array of 3 `null` references.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and clear explanation. It was very helpful and understandable.

Comment: @NarutoBijuMode You're welcome!

Comment: As addendum, the desired operation can be achieved via `test1(3, i -> Stream.generate( A::new).limit(i).toArray(A[]::new));`